# Ruby: How to make GLib::Timeout.add_seconds($second) use an array rather than one static value?

Tags: ruby, arrays, timeout, glib

When I use $second, which is an array of integers, GLib::Timeout.add_seconds($second) loads the first number in the stack and then stays the same, it keeps using that one value each iteration. I would like the timeout to load the next number in the array, and continue to the next, instead of using only the first number. The timeout seems static once it is set, is there a way to approach dynamic/changing timeout values, or loading an array as a timeout in the bellow context?

```
  def time
  true
  end    

  activator = Activator.new
  activator.window.signal_connect("key_press_event") do |_window, event|
    case event.keyval
    when Gdk::Keyval::GDK_KEY_space
      activator.time = !activator.time

    end
  end

  activator.window.set_default_size(556, 900)
  activator.window.add(activator.box)
  activator.window.show_all

  GLib::Timeout.add_seconds($second) do
    activator.nuInstance if activator.time
    true 

  end
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure doesn't look like it.  [`GLib::Timeout.add_seconds()`](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/glib2/0.90.3/symbols/GLib::Timeout/add_seconds/singleton) just calls down to [`g_timeout_add_seconds_full`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds-full).  It calls its function and if it returns true it'll call it again later, false and it'll stop.

Something to try would be instead of returning true, queue up the next timeout with the next time value from the list and return false, ending that particular timeout.

Comment: nuInstance queues the next time value and sets it as the global $second.